# QR Scanner on splash screen

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, splash-screen

I am creating Android app using Ionic Framework and angularJs. I want to Integrate QR Scanner on splash screen.I have Successfully integrated splash screen but i don't know how can I integrate QR scanner on splash screen.

Please Help

Comment: add some code here ..

Answer (score 0):

i am using this for bar code as well as QR code..!and it working..!

Html:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="scanThecode()"
                class="button button-icon  ion-ios-barcode-outline  stable header-icon"
              ng-if="user">
</button>
```

controller side:

```
 $scope.scanThecode = function() {
        $cordovaBarcodeScanner.scan().then(function(imageData) {
            if(imageData.text){
                alert(imageData.text);
            }
        }, function(error) {
        });
    };
```

[QR Code scanner lib](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/barcodeScanner/) and [Help is here](https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/09/implement-barcode-scanner-using-ionic-framework/)